# Passing dynamic parameters to a windows task scheduler job from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

Am runing a powershell script as taskscheduler job, which takes in parameters. I could pass these parameters from options in the job actions. But here i have to pass in the values to the parameters as well. But, i will be invoking this job from another powershell script which would pass in these parameter values. Is there any cleaner way i could achive this? Am taking this approach due to double hop issue.

Comment: Save the parameters in a file with `Export-CliXml`, import the values with `Import-CliXml`?

Comment: Yeah, any kind of file would work to pass settings. CliXml, CSV, JSON, etc. Whatever you're most comfortable with.

Comment: yeah, i had already considered that option. I was looking for other options if possible.